# Laptop to 4K Monitor

Tags: laptop, display, 4k-resolution

I would like to connect [this](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t430/#techspecs) (Lenovo ThinkPad T430) to [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DOPGO2G) (Seiki 39-inch 4K display), and achieve full/native 4K resolution.

Is it possible?  From the onboard mini display port to an external video card perhaps?  Which card(s) would be options?

I'm sure a newer laptop would be advisable but it needs to be this one for various reasons.

Comment: yes, it should be totally possible; lots of people report being able to connect even much older hardware to Seiki and still get 2160p.  I've provided an answer; if you find it more useful than the old answer you've accepted, then please feel free to re-accept the new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  Both the on-board [Intel HD4000](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics) graphics and the [Nvidia NVS 5400M](http://www.nvidia.ca/object/nvs_techspecs.html) have the same maximum resolution of 2560x1600.

From the Intel spec sheet linked above, newer 4th generation Intel GPUs do support 4k (3840x2160 and 4096x2304) at 60Hz.

Comment: So even an external video card approach is not feasible?  The onboard equipment is the "bottleneck"?

Comment: @Dylan it would depend on the particular external card, and whether it simply acts as an accelerator, or includes a framebuffer/video output.

Comment: I'd also add you can't connect from mini DP to an external video card. It simply dosen't work that way.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, it is certainly possible.**

[All you need is an **Active** adapter like **Accell B086B-007B**.](https://superuser.com/questions/776288/do-modern-ivy-bridge-and-haswell-graphics-support-4k/777365#777365)

As of mid-2014, it seems like there are a lot of 15 USD adapters that are advertised to support Ultra HD resolutions, but which do not appear to be as active as the active 25 USD ones by Accell, and none of those other adapters seem to be able to support Ultra HD on most of the laptops.

I've personally tried connecting ThinkPad X230 w/ Ivy-Bridge to Seiki SE39UY04 with this Accell B086B-007B-2, and it works -- I was able to get 3840x2160@30Hz, even though the spec for my X230 claims *Maximum external resolution: 2560x1600@60Hz*.  I've even tried it with a late-2008 MacBook, and to my surprise, even that combination worked!

If you search around, you'll find lots of surprised people who likewise found out that their very-very old mini-DP hardware works with Ultra HD just fine.

Comment: User Nick Lee commented: "I bought the active accell adapter after reading the post above. I don't know if I got a defective adapter, but it does not work. I have the x230 ivy-bridge and seiki 39" as well.

I tried with 2 other 1080p monitors and it didn't work. hmmm"

Comment: @Psycogeek, where did such "User Nick Lee commented", and what exactly is the value of his comment if the adapter he seems to have gotten apparently (per his own comment you mention) has failed him to produce any kind of image whatsoever with any monitor?  As I already said, this all works, pretty much the whole internet confirms that it actually works, the only people who claim that it doesn't work are simply spending too much time reading the promotional brochures (with 2560x1600@60Hz mentions) and not any time actually trying the products.

Comment: It is one user who didn't get it to work, they tried to use this format to speak, and were deleted, I put the comment where it belonged. Just one person who didn't get it to work and tried to indicate that where they learned of the information. no more no less.   You could percieve that it somehow knocks your post, or invalidates your claims, but I see it quite the opposite. The information you have (not just here) is groundbreaking, very valuable, the idea that a person might have got a clone, or a bad one, or it just did not work in some machine, doesn't invalidate possibility.

Comment: @cnst - You are using this mDP to HDMI, what if I connect mDP to DP to a 4K monitor with DP. Will X230 still drive 4K native res?

Comment: @AlexS, try it out and tell us; http://superuser.com/questions/776288/do-modern-ivy-bridge-and-haswell-graphics-support-4k/777365?noredirect=1#comment1465796_777365

Comment: @cnst - I cant as I dont have the machine, I will buy used if it can be done over mDP/ DP and not HDMI